# Performance in SQL Server

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008

I have a problem in a Program that runs queries on a mssql 2008 database.
I did some research in the query analyzer.
There is a strange issue with the following two queries:

```
SELECT  BOLD_ID ,
        BOLD_TYPE
FROM    ZusatzKlasseBase
WHERE   ( bold_id IN ( SELECT   usereintrag
                       FROM     zusatzfeld
                       WHERE    metazusatzfeld = 5211309
                                AND wertobject = 1298369 )
          AND bold_id IN ( SELECT   usereintrag
                           FROM     zusatzfeld
                           WHERE    metazusatzfeld = 5207783
                                    AND wertdatum = '20130415' )
        )
```

Runtime vor this query is about one second

```
SELECT  BOLD_ID ,
        BOLD_TYPE
FROM    ZusatzKlasseBase
WHERE   ( BOLD_TYPE IN ( 336 ) )
        AND ( bold_id IN ( SELECT   usereintrag
                           FROM     zusatzfeld
                           WHERE    metazusatzfeld = 5211309
                                    AND wertobject = 1298369 )
              AND bold_id IN ( SELECT   usereintrag
                               FROM     zusatzfeld
                               WHERE    metazusatzfeld = 5207783
                                        AND wertdatum = '20130415' )
            )
```

The runtime of this query is one minute.

I have no explanation for this, the field BOLD_TYPE is indexed.
Can anyone guess why the more specific query is slower?

Thanks for all answers in advance.

Comment: Just out of interest, why are you executing the `select usereintrag from zusatzfeld where ...` piece of code twice?  Why not just optimise the code with multiple sets of logical criteria?

Comment: How different are the execution plans?

Comment: Well, is there an index on BOLD_TYPE? How many rows in the table? How many rows have the value 336?

Comment: @Westie The SQL-statement is generated by a standard-erp-software. The reason for this is, that it is generic code. If I had a clue on the reason for this, i could request a change.

Comment: @AaronBertrand : The field is not selective, that means, there is no gain in using it. Do you mean this could be the reason?

Comment: @chris seeing as that is the only difference in the queries, that seems to be a valid guess, yes. And I discovered not too long ago that even non-selective columns can be useful as part of the key of an index (I held the opposite perception for years). Impossible to know, though, without seeing actual execution plans.

Comment: @Westie that doesn't really seem to be the problem, as the first queries performs "well enough" - and combining the logic might just give the optimizer fits trying to come up with a perfect plan to satisfy either condition. I would first suggest changing `IN` to a correlated `EXISTS`, as that may stand to provide more obvious benefit and also might be easier to incorporate into the ERP code.

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks for your answer. I will look into the execution plan.

Comment: @AaronBertrand i looked into the execution plan. The difference is in the first nested loop. It is executed on a non clustered index in the slower case.

Comment: @Chris - I see; fair enough.  (at) AaronBertrand - No that's fine.  It was more interest in the why, really than the solution for the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the index on `bold_id` (I assume there is an index on `bold_id`) to this:

```
CREATE INDEX whatever ON dbo.ZusatzKlasseBase(bold_id, bold_type)
  WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON);
```

Then I would re-write the query slightly:

```
SELECT  BOLD_ID,
        BOLD_TYPE
FROM dbo.ZusatzKlasseBase AS b -- always use schema prefix
WHERE
    ( BOLD_TYPE IN ( 336 ) )
    AND EXISTS 
    (
      SELECT 1 FROM dbo.zusatzfeld
      WHERE    metazusatzfeld = 5211309
               AND wertobject = 1298369 
               AND usereintrag = b.bold_id
    )
    AND EXISTS
    ( 
       SELECT 1 FROM dbo.zusatzfeld
       WHERE    metazusatzfeld = 5207783
                AND wertdatum = '20130415' 
                AND usereintrag = b.bold_id
    );
```